# Unable to find httpd directory in Amazon EC2 to configure PhpMyAdmin

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I am new to amazon servers. I have Installed PhpMyadmin in my Amazon EC2 server. To access my server's PhpMyadmin from my PC it seems I need to configure some files. According to [this link](http://sanketdangi.com/post/56623052533/phpmyadmin-on-amazon-ec2-manage-amazon-rds) I need to change the file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` But there's no directory or file named 'httpd' in /etc directory. Where can I find the httpd directory? How can I configure my machine to access phpmyadmin? I almost tried every solution in stackoverflow and none of them worked for me. Any help is appreciable.

Comment: @Suraj you can find the file by using the find command: find / -type f -name phpMyAdmin.conf.

Comment: How did you install phpMyAdmin -- with your distribution's package manager or by downloading the source to your web root folder?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to configure web-server on your ec2 instance. You can install  apache as a webserver.

**For RHEL/Amazon/Fedora Distro issue following commands:-**

```
sudo yum install httpd
```

Then make changes in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` according to the Link you are using and restart the apache web server.

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

You can access PHPMyAdmin by http://ec2-ip-address/phpmyadmin

**For Ubuntu/Debian Distro issue following commands:-**

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Then make changes in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf` according to the Link you are using and restart the apache web server.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You can access PHPMyAdmin by http://ec2-ip-address/phpmyadmin